# Search on multiple column vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a document with datas and I want to automatize a research.

for exemple I have

```
| lastName | firstName | age | result
```

And I'd like to get the result row where lastName = Smith, firstName = Jhon and age = 42

I know how to do that with loops but the complexity is hight is there an other solution ?

Comment: You could use [**Autofilter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx). See my [**answer here for more details**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091948/searching-over-multiple-columns-in-excel-vba/21092259#21092259).

Comment: is `result` numeric, and if so, will the other columns be unique (no chance of duplication), or if duplication is possible, a sum of the corresponding values is the desired return result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try This array formula:

```
=INDEX(D2:D10;MATCH(1;(A2:A10="Smith")*(B2:B10="John")*(C2:C11=42);0))
```

This is an array formula so you need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula

Answer (score 1):

CRondao has a good solution that will return the first match, and works on any data type. If `result` is numeric and you want to sum up all matches, this will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$4="Smith"),--($B$1:$B$4="Jhon"),--($C$1:$C$4=42),$D$1:$D$4)
```

Note, this is not an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I usually build a "lookup key" by using `CONCATENATE()` to combine the values.  I can then return results using `VLOOKUP()` or `SUMIF()` as required since I find those functions intuitve and easier to write than range offset/index/match formulas.

Here's an image of a demo worksheet, upper left cell is "A1":

[image: MultiLookup.xls]

If there are multiple matches, you'll see the total count immediately.  You can also use the Auto-Filter, etc., etc....

Here are the formulas in the filter row:

```
A3: =CONCATENATE(B3,C3,D3)
E3: =SUMIF($A$5:$A$10,$A$3,E$5:E$10)
F3: =VLOOKUP($A$3,$A$5:$F$10,6,FALSE)
```

Since `F3` is using `VLOOKUP()` with option `FALSE`, it will only return the first result it finds in the list, otherwise it returns `#N/A`.

These are the formulas in the first row of data, which can be copied down to cover the entire range:

```
A6: =CONCATENATE(B6,C6,D6)
E6: =IF($A6=$A$3,1,"")
F6: =IF($A6=$A$3,ROW(),"")
```