# Find the Row of a String Value in a Column while Criteria are met in the same Row but the other Columns

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

Ok i am trying to find a value from a `Column`. This `Column` has about 600 `values`. While it is not a problem to find the value for example "Lassie" and locate that it is on `Cell A301` it creates a problem the fact that i need to check the `Row` which the `value` Lassie is (here it is 301) and search if other criteria are being met.

*I need something like this:*

- If the value in `CellA301` is "Sales Revenue, Net` and,
- If the value in `CellK301 = Start_Period`
- If the value in `CellL301 = End_Period`
- If the values in `CellM301 = ""` and `CellN301 = ""` and `CellO301 = ""` and `CellP301 = ""` and `CellQ301 = ""`

Then if **all these conditions are met** i need to `copy` the `CellH301` and `paste` it in another `Sheet`

The **trick** is that i cannot search for `CellA301` first and if it equaled to "Sales Revenue, Net" do all the other tests **because there are numerous cells in column A which are populated with the String Value "Sales Revenue, Net" and only the one that meets the above conditions altogether is the correct one.**

**EDIT**

```
Sub wussss()

''disable autofilter in case it's already enabled'
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("31_December_2010").AutoFilterMode = False

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("31_December_2010").Range("A1:AZ1")
    'set autofilter'
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Sales Revenue, Net"
    .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="1/1/2010"
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="12/31/2010" 'x
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="" 'X  IT FAILS HERE
    .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=""
    .AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:=""

End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox Rng.Row ' returns first visible row number
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False 'disable autofilter'
End Sub
```

Comment: this might be helpful: [Searching over multiple columns in excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091948/searching-over-multiple-columns-in-excel-vba/21092259#21092259). Another way - add additional column with formula: `=AND(A1="Sales Revenue, Net",K1="something",L1="something else",..)` and find row where this formula returns `True`

Comment: I don't know what this `Autofilter` does `Criteria1` i am reading it now. Also on me the columns which i need to do things are always fixed

Comment: @simoco does is to stand programmatically to compile all "Sales Revenue, Net" in a `collection` and then search everyone of them for these criteria or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: why autofilter doesn't suit?

Comment: @simoco i havent tested that solution to be honest i will try out what `Autofilter` does however i think it searches a table. In my case the columns are fixed what holds what type of value. I'll give you feedback i will try that solution now

Comment: I went to MS Help looks promising i better put down my lazy ass down to test it!

Comment: @simoco if i want to search with this way over 80 times do you think is ok to use `Autofilter`? it produces dropdown buttons on the top and i need to search for other values in this way i am worried it may not pull the correct data on the other iterations..

Comment: Do you believe with control flow and boolean statements would be better it is a long macro what is better for execution time?

Comment: `i want to search with this way over 80 times` - I would create additional column with formula (maybe throught vba) `=AND(A1="Sales Revenue, Net",K1="something",L1="something else",..)` and find row with `TRUE` result

Comment: I am quite getting the ropes it looks good. @simoco do you believe it is practical to use that method in order to search for over 100 elements per sheet?

Comment: `Autofilter` looks great and i will try this another column method to. Can you offer me your opinion if you believe it is the most efficient way? I am searching a massive load of data...

Comment: @simoco i am testing it the `Autofilter` it works fine but after 15 Fields it produces an error saying: `Run-time error `1004` AutoFilter method of Range class failed`. Why is it happening ? :P

Comment: without seeing your code it's hard to tell what is wrong with it

Comment: @simoco sorry i have edited and added the code. After `Field:=13` i need to be sure that all will be empty until `Field:=30` but it fails on `Field:=15`

Comment: Otherwise it is truly perfect for my needs

Comment: do you have merged cells on worksheet?

Comment: yes i have merged cells. there is only one that always starts from `M1` always and according to data load it stays merged sometimes until `T1` (`M1:T1`) and other times until `AZ1` (`M1:AZ1`) it is always on the first `row` this `merged cell`

Comment: I'll check it out i think you truly nailed it~

Comment: I dont get it i have unmerged the cell but it still fails

Comment: any chance to see your workbook?

Comment: Certainly i will post a picture now!

Comment: I will try to find a location to upload it

Comment: you can use e.g. https://www.dropbox.com (btw workbook file would be better than just picture)

Comment: @simoco https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NcO6tBLZg5Yjk0Tjl5QkV0WTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this works and anyone with link can download it.

Comment: `Module2` is the testing script and main work of my code is at `aWorks` module.

Comment: I've figured it out. Autofiler works only with "Used part" of sheet. So, add `.Value = .Value` line just after `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("31_December_2010").Range("A1:AZ1")` (to make `A1:AZ1` as used part of sheet). Btw in your code don't forget to change `Sheet1` to `31_December_2010`

Comment: @simoco you're the man!!! testing it now.

Comment: @simoco IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 YEAH YOU'RE THE MAN. If you put it in writing in a few lines i will happily mark as correct and edit titles etc for other users to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this code works:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("31_December_2010")
        'disable autofilter in case it's already enabled'
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:AZ1")
            .Value = .Value
            'set autofilter'
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Sales Revenue, Net"
            .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="1/1/2010"
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="12/31/2010" 'x
            For i = 13 To 30
                .AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:=""
            Next i
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng.Row ' returns first visible row number

        .AutoFilterMode = False 'disable autofilter'
    End With
End Sub
```

Also little note:

You can apply `AutoFilter` only on used part of sheet. E.g. if last column of `UsedRange` is `M`, in line `.Range("A1:AZ1").Autofilter` Excel aplies filter only for `A1:M1`. However part `.Value = .Value` of the code above, explicitly adds `A1:AZ1` to used part of sheet.

Comment: I will edit my question better tommorow! Now it's time for a drink. I'll drink one on ya!