# Excel VBA Select a row based on its multi-column data matching criteria in multiple userform comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, combobox, commandbutton

This is a solution I am interested in implementing but I am unsure of my syntax, I will provide an example of what I have below. I believe a similar result can be found using an AutoFilter method, but I wish to avoid this if possible. I am basing my attempts so far on a suggestion from Søren Holten Hansen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091948/searching-over-multiple-columns-in-excel-vba) that uses nested if statements to return the row number that matches criteria contained within TextBoxes.

For background, I currently have a UserForm1 that contains **five ComboBoxes** and **two Command Buttons**.

Each ComboBox pre-populates with the contents of a named range housing data that corresponds to data on Sheet1, such as "Fruits" in ComboBox1 and Column A of Sheet1, "Vegetables" in ComboBox2 and Column B of Sheet1, and so on.

My goal is to use nested If statements when CommandButton1 is clicked to find and Select the entire row on Sheet 1 which contains an exact match to the value of each ComboBox. For example, if the user selects 'Apple' from ComboBox1, 'Potato' from ComboBox2, 'Farm' from ComboBox 3, 'Monkey' from ComboBox4, and 'Supermarket' from ComboBox5, the entire row on Sheet1 that contains 'Apple' in Column A, 'Potato' in Column B, 'Farm' in Column C', 'Monkey' in Column D, and 'Supermarket' from Column E is then selected.

What I have so far is the following, assigned to CommandButton1:

```
Dim i As Long, GetRow As Long
    For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value Then
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value Then
                    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox4.Value Then
                        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = Me.ComboBox5.Value Then
                    GetRow = i
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
Next i
Rows(i).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

I believe the desired result can be achieved using nested If statements, but I am unsure of my formatting in this example.

Thank you.

Comment: I think this would much easier using a SQL statement with ADO. Here's a good example from MSDN to get you started: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx. Basically you would just add the ComboBox choices as conditions in the Where Clause of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method of `Range` object, like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mySelection As Range

    With Sheet1
        With Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            For i = 1 To 5
                .AutoFilter field:=i, criteria1:=Me.Controls("Combobox" & i)
            Next i
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set mySelection = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    If Not mySelection Is Nothing Then mySelection.Select
End Sub
```